# What can cause a segmentation fault in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

We have a mongodb replica set, on of the member crashed with a segmentation fault. What could be causing this issue? We are running version 2.2.2.

Thanks. Here is the log from the crash.

```
Mon Sep  2 03:37:26 Invalid access at address: 0xfffffd7d00680038 from thread: conn2014070

Mon Sep  2 03:37:26 Got signal: 11 (Segmentation Fault).

Mon Sep  2 03:37:26 Backtrace:
0xb331b8 0x7bd48b 0x7bd695 0xfffffd7fff1d7666 0xfffffd7fff1ca35c 0x9ff980 0x873f13 0x873fcb 0x981331 0x982af2 0x92d2da 0x93183b 0x7cead0 0xb2539a 0xfffffd7ff95f364c 0xfffffd7fff1d72d4 0xfffffd7fff1d75a0 
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x28 [0xb331b8]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x11b [0x7bd48b]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo24abruptQuitWithAddrSignalEiP7siginfoPv+0x125 [0x7bd695]
 /lib/amd64/libc.so.1'__sighndlr+0x6 [0xfffffd7fff1d7666]
 /lib/amd64/libc.so.1'call_user_handler+0x2a4 [0xfffffd7fff1ca35c]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZNK5mongo6Record5touchEb+0x0 [0x9ff980]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo12ClientCursor5yieldEiPNS_6RecordE+0x63 [0x873f13]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo12ClientCursor14yieldSometimesENS0_11RecordNeedsEPb+0x6b [0x873fcb]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo14_updateObjectsEbPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES4_bbbRNS_7OpDebugEPNS_11RemoveSaverEbRKNS_24QueryPlanSelectionPolicyEb+0x9a1 [0x981331]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo13updateObjectsEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES4_bbbRNS_7OpDebugEbRKNS_24QueryPlanSelectionPolicyE+0xa2 [0x982af2]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo14receivedUpdateERNS_7MessageERNS_5CurOpE+0x27a [0x92d2da]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0xe9b [0x93183b]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0x90 [0x7cead0]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo3pms9threadRunEPNS_13MessagingPortE+0x32a [0xb2539a]
 /opt/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.49.0'thread_proxy+0x6c [0xfffffd7ff95f364c] /lib/amd64/libc.so.1'_thrp_setup+0xbc [0xfffffd7fff1d72d4]
 /lib/amd64/libc.so.1'_lwp_start+0x0 [0xfffffd7fff1d75a0]
```

Additionally I am seeing some assertion failures before the crash, I am not sure whether they are related. Otherwise nothing else out of the ordinary as far as I can see.

```
Wed Sep  4 02:19:04 [conn988803]  cratefm Assertion failure !e.eoo() src/mongo/db/../bson/bsonobjbuilder.h 131
0xb331b8 0xb01e70 0x7cbe04 0x88e7ec 0x8b5f18 0x8b6b66 0x8b714a 0x978044 0x97ab32 0x931065 0x7cead0 0xb2539a 0xfffffd7fdd1a364c 0xfffffd7fff1d72d4 0xfffffd7fff1d75a0 
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x28 [0xb331b8]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0xc0 [0xb01e70]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'0x3cbe04 [0x7cbe04]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo16CmdFindAndModify3runERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x65c [0x88e7ec]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x48 [0x8b5f18]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo11execCommandEPNS_7CommandERNS_6ClientEiPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0xa26 [0x8b6b66]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo12_runCommandsEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x37a [0x8b714a]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo11runCommandsEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_5CurOpERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x34 [0x978044]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo8runQueryERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERNS_5CurOpES1_+0x6c2 [0x97ab32]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0x6c5 [0x931065]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0x90 [0x7cead0]
 /opt/local/bin/mongod'_ZN5mongo3pms9threadRunEPNS_13MessagingPortE+0x32a [0xb2539a]
 /opt/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.49.0'thread_proxy+0x6c [0xfffffd7fdd1a364c]
 /lib/amd64/libc.so.1'_thrp_setup+0xbc [0xfffffd7fff1d72d4]
 /lib/amd64/libc.so.1'_lwp_start+0x0 [0xfffffd7fff1d75a0]
```

Comment: I got sig fault couple of times. You should post this to  https://jira.mongodb.org

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to the latest 2.2 version?  2.2.6 is current - many bugs were fixed since 2.2.2.  In addition, not enough log is provided - what was happening immediately leading up to the crash?

Comment: there was nothing out of the ordinary before the crash. this has started happening more often than randomly of late. i will probably upgrade to 2.2.6 but before that i want to make sure there isn't something else i am missing.

Comment: our machines are hosted at joyent, and i found a reference to the following bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10433?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel - could it be it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your client version >= server version.

Check out https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8105

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug from the 2.6 version when updating arrays on documents with more than 128 BSON elements:

[Here is the issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13516?jql=project%20=%20SERVER%20AND%20fixVersion%20=%20%222.6.1%22%20AND%20text%20~%20%22segmentation%20fault%22)

As they say, it's corrected since the 2.6.1 version, so i encourage you to upgrade as i did, everything works great for me now !